# How to properly setup an activation hook

Tags: hooks, oop, activation, warnings

I am trying to register an activation hook for my plugin. The plugin is using classes and the actual activation method is held in a separate admin class. Reading the documentation for [`register_activation_hook()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) it seems like the first parameter `$file` should always be the file of the main plugin file:

> Path to the main plugin file inside the wp-content/plugins directory.
>   A full path will work.

The two classes are kept in separate files, which looks something like this.

This is the main plugin file:

```
<?php 
/* my-plugin.php */

include_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/admin/my-plugin-admin.php');

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('MyPluginAdmin', 'activate'));

class MyPlugin {
}
```

While this is the admin part, which also contains the activation routine:

```
<?php
/* my-plugin-admin.php */

class MyPluginAdmin {
  public static function activate() {
    // This method is called in both cases,
    // but in the first example a php warning is generated
  }
}
```

My problem is that static `activate` method is actually triggered on activation, but I still get a php warning which looks like this:

```
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'MyPluginAdmin' not found in /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287
PHP Stack trace:
1. {main}() /var/www/html/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php:0
2. activate_plugin($plugin = 'my-plugin/my-plugin.php', $redirect = 'http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php?error=true&plugin=my-plugin%2Fmy-plugin.php', $network_wide = FALSE, $silent = *uninitialized*) /var/www/html/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php:43
3. do_action($tag = 'activate_my-plugin/my-plugin.php', $arg = FALSE) /var/www/html/wp/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php:586
4. WP_Hook->do_action($args = array (0 => FALSE)) /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:453
5. WP_Hook->apply_filters($value = '', $args = array (0 => FALSE)) /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:311
6. call_user_func_array:{/var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:287}(array (0 => 'MyPluginAdmin', 1 => 'activate'), array (0 => FALSE)) /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:287
```

If I change the call to `register_activation_hook()` into:

```
register_activation_hook(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/admin/my-plugin-admin.php', array('MyPluginAdmin', 'activate'));
```

Then the warning message disappears. 
So, my question is what is the correct way to use `register_activation_hook()` and why does it work in both above cases although it throws a warning in the first scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You first example looks corrent. There is however a typo, hence `class 'MyPluginAdmin' not found`.

You include `myplugin-admin.php`, but then your question seems to suggest the page holding the class is in fact `my-plugin-admin.php` (with a hypen).

If I correct the typo and run the code there are no warnings.

Edit (this works correctly):

my-plugin.php:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: my-plugin.php
*/

include_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/my-plugin-admin.php');

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('MyPluginAdmin', 'activate'));

class MyPlugin {
}
```

my-plugin-admin.php:

```
<?php
/* my-plugin-admin.php */

class MyPluginAdmin {
  public static function activate() {
  }
}
```

With `my-plugin.php` and `my-plugin-admin.php` both in the same directory. Does `my-plugin-admin.php` have the correct permissions?

Comment: That was just a typo, the path to the file is correct, so this seems not to be the problem.

Comment: @Cyclonecode your second version activates the plugin, but the activation function isn't run. The $file parameter is definitely incorrect, you end up with something like `my-plugin.php/my-plugin-admin.php`. Are both of the files in the same directory?

Comment: The `MyPluginAdmin::activate` method are run in both cases? The real plugin has its admin file located in a subfolder i.e `admin/my-plugin-admin.php`. Very strange that only the second version works without throwing a warning?

Comment: @Cyclonecode No, `MyPluginAdmin::activate` is not run in the second version. You can test this by just putting an `echo` in the activate function (activation hooks aren't allowed to output). The first example fails to activate with a `The plugin generated x characters of unexpected output during activation.` whereas the second activates as the function is not run. Are you including the directory in the include ie. `include_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'admin/my-plugin-admin.php');` , because you haven't in your example code.

Comment: Yes of course I'm including the directory path in the second example. The path is absolutely correct, since it is the same path used for including the actual file. The above is just an example, shouldn't matter if it is in a sub folder as long as the path is correct. I updated the question to match the actual structure of my plugin files.

Comment: @Cyclonecode I've tested the code in my answer and it works, if yours is the same, I don't see why yours doesn't. The error clearly states `class 'MyPluginAdmin' not found`. If you're sure the include is correct, then the only other things I can think of is a typo in class name or incorrect permissions. I'm sure if you create a function in `MyPluginAdmin` and call it from the main class, you will get an error. The `MyPLuginAdmin` is not included.